# Can updates of online C++ Standard Draft invalidate links to it?

Tags: c++

Links to the online C++ Stadnard Draft at http://eel.is/c++draft/ may contain **paragraph and sentence numbers**, such as: `http://eel.is/c++draft/description#structure.summary-1.sentence-2`. I wonder what happens when the Draft is updated, e.g, when some paragraphs/sentences are added in front of existing paragraph/sentences. This would shift their numbers and possibly invalidate links, wouldn't it?. However, there are many such links on SO but I haven't seen a single invalid one.

Comment: This really sounds like it should be on meta, not main.  FWIW this is why I always cite the section as a link.  For instance I'll use [\[expr.const.cast\]/4.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const.cast#4.3) so if the link breaks you at least know what I was referring to.

Comment: @NathanOliver I wasn't sure since I though Meta should contain only questions about SO, which is not my case: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta.

Comment: On second thought this might not be a meta question, but It still feels that way to me.  Not sure if it should be a C++ question but I have no idea what else to tag it with or where else to ask.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have the very same feeling about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links to sections are generally fine.  The C++ standard uses named sections that are fairly stable between standard revisions.  Subsections may be moved around between parent sections (that's why you have things like [intro.object] being a subsection of [basic] rather than [intro]), but, while I'm not sure if it's a hard rule, they don't generally get renamed or removed.

Links to paragraphs within a section aren't as stable.  They will continue to *work*, but they may not point to the paragraph you intended after a later standard revision.  AFAIK there is no effort made to keep paragraph numbering consistent between standard revisions.

Comment: Re: "while I'm not sure if it's a hard rule" -- it's a hard rule -- tags don't change. The one exception is the move from C++03 to C++11, when I removed the "lib." from the beginning of all the library sections. Being a library guy, I didn't like making it look like the was library a second-class citizen. Fortunately, this didn't result in any duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

Numbering does indeed change over time, which invalidates links. For increased stability, you can make links to the specific versions of the draft that Tim Song publishes at https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp/tree/master .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35285488)